# Why does sumif() fail with certain values unless I math manipulate them?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a perplexing issue with `sumif()` in a Google Spreadsheet.  It is correctly summing some, but not all, of the values that match the required critera.  If however I take the value that is failing to be summed, and divide it by 1, then the sumif functions correctly.

Also I have found that using `round()` around the "offending" data also causes the `sumif()` to function correctly.  So it seems that this particular value just requires some extra manipulation, but I don't know why.  The value is simply a cell reference to another cell containing a numeric value.

Why on earth would this be happening and how can I get sumif to behave consistently without having to mathematically manipulate certain cells?

Comment: That was it!  Feel free to post as an answer if you like.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure, just felt I should give credit where it was due.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @pnuts pointed out, this was merely an issue of formatting.  Most of the data I was pulling from another sheet was in fact formatted numerically, but just a few cells were for some reason formatted as text, and therefore the `sumif()` was failing to include them unless mathematically altered, forcing them to a text type.

The solution was simply to go into my main data sheet, and format all cells as numeric in the format I needed.